# How to know if it's my harddrive which slows down compilation significantly?

Tags: compiling, performance

I recently purchased a Dell work station with a the following CPU

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70GHz

It has 10 cores with two threads each.

But when I compile a tex file as simple as

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  Hello world.
\end{document}
```

It takes 30 seconds with lualatex and about the same time with pdflatex.

I noticed that CPU workload is pretty low during the compilation.
So I guess it's my 2TB mechanical hard drive which slows everything significantly.
Is there anyway to verify this?

Comment: If you compile directly from the terminal/command prompt then you can see the individual steps of the compilation in real time, which should give you an idea what causes the delays. Maybe the formats are rebuilt every time, or the fonts, or locating the class and style files takes a long time. Maybe a virus scanner is interfering. Maybe the files are in a folder that is synchronized with the cloud (Dropbox or similar). Posting the full log file from your simple file here (as edit to your question) may also help in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: make sure you have TEXINPUTS set correctly so it uses the pre cached ls-r files and is not searching your disk for each file

Comment: use `pdflatex --kpathsea-debug=-1 yourfile` and check that packages and fonts are found via hash lookup, eg `kdebug:hash_lookup(cmss10.pfb)` not by searching your disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I finally found the problem.

I am using a cloud storage service [pCloud](https://www.pcloud.com/) to synchronize my `~/texmf` folder across several computers. On this one where things are extremely slow, I am using the pCloud version of my `texmf` folder. That is why it's extremely slow.

I should have used the [synchronization](https://www.pcloud.com/features/synchronization.html) feature of pcloud. This speeds things up tremendously.